# Why is this simple Angular code not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just playing around with Angular and I can't get it to work. The binding works when I set my ng-app="" and nothing else. 
This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script  src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<ul ng-repeat="x in names">
    <li >
        {{ x }}
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

And my app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.names = ['a', 'b'];
});
```

Yes the js files are in the right place and refrenced properly. I'm using WebStorm. 
I keep seeing the {{x}} on my page. Instead of the names inside the scope.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/rxjzxaqo/

Comment: You are loading `angular.js` later. Try to load first before `app.js`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app.js should be linked after angular:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
        <li>
            {{ x }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```